# How to manually write a yaml file

Tags: syntax, yaml

I am trying to write a YAML file but its very new to me and I can't figure out the nesting part.

Is it possible to write a file like so?

```
Manager : me@here.com
    custid : 380
    employees :
        - Wright
        - Thompson
        - Hope

Manager: me2@here.com
    custid : 381
    employees :
       - Smith
       - Jones
```

Every time I write this, I keep getting errors,

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
```

This happens after the custid part. Why is this happening?

Comment: I edited out your request for off-site documentation, that is outside of the scope you are allowed to ask about here on [so]. If you google for YAML specification you should get to the official site, but I have to warn that  the specification is not very accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems lies in the lines with `Manager :`. For the first you start a mapping there with key `Manager` and scalar value `me@here.com`, then on the following line you continue indented with more two key  value pairs. Because of your indentation the parser has no idea where to attach these.

You probably want to do:

```
- Manager : me@here.com
  custid : 380
  employees :
        - Wright
        - Thompson
        - Hope

- Manager: me2@here.com
  custid : 381
  employees :
       - Smith
       - Jones
```

i.e. a list of two managers each consisting of a mapping, with three keys (Manager, custid, employees).

You can also make the manager position implicit and the email a key:

```
me@here.com:
  custid : 380
  employees :
        - Wright
        - Thompson
        - Hope

me2@here.com:
  custid : 381
  employees :
       - Smith
       - Jones
```

but in that case the emails have to be unique.

You can also use more complex keys at the top level (so you can have the same email as long as the role is different) ¹:

```
[Manager, me@here.com]:
  custid : 380
  employees :
        - Wright
        - Thompson
        - Hope

[Manager, me2@here.com]:
  custid : 381
  employees :
       - Smith
       - Jones
```

But the general rule is that if you don't have some **unique** identifying key for each record, you need to use a list.

---

¹ <sub>This form is keys is AFAIK not supported by PyYAML but my [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) parser can handle these kind of (valid) YAML keys</sub>

Comment: OK I get what you are saying. I want to return the set of employees to my Python program depending on which Manager is selected. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure but either you make a list of managers and walk over that list to select a value for a specific key to find a specific manager, or you rearrange your structure and have toplevel a mapping with e.g. the unique email address as key and the rest as value for that key, or you make a complex key. I'll update my answer with alternatives.

Comment: Thank you! The part where you made "the manager position implicit and the email a key", was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Yaml only recognizes spaces so if you are using Tab for indentation maybe that's what causing your problems. [Here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) is the official documentation to get you started.

Comment: I'm not using tab, I am using spaces,   Why cant I put a value after "Manager" because it will work if i remove the email addresses associated with 'Manager'